# Getting the object of another obect

Tags: java, constructor

If I have two classes, Player and BankAccount. When a player object is created using a constructor, a bank account object is automatically created and assigned with the same "ID" as the player object. How would I get a player's bank account if I created a new player and called it "player1"?

For example, how would I achieve player1.getBankAccount(); and be able to return the balance using the getter than I created in the BankAccount class? Like somehow use the player's 'ID', and get their bankaccount from it.
Thank you, sorry if this doesn't make much sense.

Player Class:

```
public Player(String name, BankAccount b, int id) {
    this.name = name;
    this.id = id;
    BankAccount bank = new BankAccount(); // assigning a NEW bank
                                           account for
                                          a new player when a player object is created
}
```

Bank Account class:

```
public BankAccount(Player p, double balance) {
    this.p = p;
    this.balance = 10000.00;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Please at least try to use inheritance & poly. For example, your base class could be BankAccount with a getter to access the balance:

```
    public class BankAccount
{
    private double balance;

    public BankAccount(double balance)
    {
        this.balance = balance;
    }

    public double getBalance()
    {
        return balance;
    }
}
```

Then create Player as a child class inheriting from BankAccount:

```
public class Player extends BankAccount
{
    private String name;
    private int id;

    public Player(String name, int id)
    {
        super(10000.00);
        this.name = name;
        this.id = id;
    }
}
```

Then access the getter inherited from BankAccount:

```
Player player1 = new Player("playerName", 1234567);
player1.getBalance();
```

To do the other thing..."*Like somehow use the player's 'ID', and get their bankaccount from it.*" ,  you could try something where as long as the instance of Player contains the id parameter or whatever parameter, it will return your other fields. Of course in your example the id is always required, so this only makes sense where you have overloaded the constructor to make it "optional":

```
public class Player extends BankAccount
{
    private String name;
    private String id;

    //Constructors
    public Player(String name, String id)
    {
        super(10000.00);
        this.name = name;
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Player(String name)
    {
        super(10000.00);
        this.name = name;
    }

    //Public method
    public String validateInstance(Player player)
    {
        if(player.id.isEmpty())
        {
            return "the instance has no id";
        }
        return getDetails();
    }

    //Getters
    private String getDetails()
    {
        return (getName() + " " + getId());
    }

    private String getName()
    {
        return name;
    }

    private String getId()
    {
        return id;
    }
}
```

Then use it like this for example:

```
player1.validateInstance(player1)
```

You should be able to tweak this approach to achieve exactly what you want.